# How to load JavaScript files from GitHub externally?

Tags: javascript, css, github

How can I load a JavaScript file from raw.github.com? This code for CSS works perfectly well:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://raw.github.com/myusername/myrepo/master/style.css">
```

But it will not work for JavaScript:

```html
<script src="https://raw.github.com/myusername/myrepo/master/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: github is not a cdn. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @user2736012 It worked for CSS, I was wondering why it didn't work for JavaScript.

Comment: Do not do this github is not a CDN...

Comment: @Ptr13: Yes, I know. I read that in your question.

Comment: Using **cdn.jsdelivr.net** `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/<username>/<repository>/<file>`, For example pasing from `https://raw.github.com/myusername/myrepo/master/style.css` to `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/myusername/myrepo/style.css`.

Comment: This is now possible using https://www.jsdelivr.com/

Comment: Use JsDelivr. https://github.com/PrismJS/live/blob/master/src/prism-live.js becomes `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/prismjs@1.29.0/prism.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You cannot load JavaScript from Github because the content type is not `application/javascript` or `text/javascript`.

This is done intentionally to prevent you from using Github as a CDN, which is in violation of their terms of service.

See also:  https://rawgithub.com/

And this:  https://github.com/blog/1482-heads-up-nosniff-header-support-coming-to-chrome-and-firefox

Comment: Huh. Well. Can I just delete that question?

Comment: @Ptr13, What for?  Why not just accept the answer so that others can find it in the future?  StackOverflow is for learning from everyone's questions/answers, not just for getting your own personal question answered.

Comment: @Brad: I don't think using GitHub as a CDN is against their ToS. It's just that the directory structure isn't guaranteed to be static for a repository, so your site can break unexpectedly.

Comment: @Blender I've seen it in their ToS before... let me see if I can dig it up.

Comment: *Abuse or excessively frequent requests to GitHub via the API may result in the temporary or permanent suspension of your account's access to the API. GitHub, in its sole discretion, will determine abuse or excessive usage of the API. GitHub will make a reasonable attempt via email to warn the account owner prior to suspension. If your bandwidth usage significantly exceeds the average bandwidth usage (as determined solely by GitHub) of other GitHub customers, we reserve the right to immediately disable your account or throttle your file hosting until you can reduce your bandwidth consumption.*

Comment: I guess that's not quite use-raw-as-hosting-and-you're-in-violation as much as it is don't-do-things-that-aren't-nice-or-we'll-be-unhappy, but the principal applies.

Comment: See this as well:  https://github.com/blog/1482-heads-up-nosniff-header-support-coming-to-chrome-and-firefox

Comment: @Brad: You're right. I guess I'm not too good at skimming legal documents.