# Raw Github js file not loading (direct link) like CDN

Tags: javascript, html, github, github-pages, cdn

I created a coding library for the public to use by putting a `<script>` tag in the `<head>` tag on the page but when I try to use the a function it says `undefined` when it ran.

. I linked the url to the `index.js` file but it doesn't load it to the client user.

```html
<head>
<script src="https://github.com/<username>/<repo>/blob/master/index.js"></script>
</head>
```

When I run a `console.log(ranInteger(1,10))` which I have defined in my `index.js` file but I get a `ranInteger is not defined`  error. All help is welcome!

Comment: the url is invalid, shows an error to me

Comment: @nihiser — No, that's an HTML document showing a syntax highlighted version of the file.

Comment: **Github is not a web hosting service or CDN**. It hosts Git repositories. If you want a CDN use CloudFront or something.

Comment: I did try using `github user content ` to the same problem @Quentin also people do use git as a download site for releases

Comment: @JoeMcMullan — No, different problem. Similar cause: Github is not a web hosting service or CDN. It hosts Git repositories. If you want a CDN use CloudFront or something.

Comment: So you saying its impossible to do @Quentin ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19285701/12513827

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking, GitHub doesn't allow source code to be accessed from their site like a CDN, however from [This StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285686/how-to-load-javascript-files-from-github-externally/), there is a workaround. I wouldn't recommend using it, but you can use "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/" to get your script to work (from user @anayarojo on StackOverflow).

The url in your case would look like this:

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/McJoe21/coderslib/index.js
```

The pattern for the URL is:
`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/<username>/<repository>/<file>`

Comment: @JoeMcMullan That's gonna be a separate problem. module.exports doesn't work as a vanilla javascript feature, module.exports is only going to work in a node.js runtime environment, so you can't just import it in a plain HTML page

Comment: But @JohnnyLeek shouldn't the browser just ignore that part the do the rest

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load JavaScript from raw version of Github because the content type(MIME type) is  `text/plain`, not `application/javascript` or `text/javascript`. This is to stop you using Github as a CDN. Still you can achieve serving raw file as cdn in the following way, using `cdn.jsdelivr.net`.

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/<github-username>/<github-repo-name@branch-name>/<filename>
```

If file is at `main` branch, no need to include in branch section after `@`. If you mention also, it'll work.

[For more reference](https://rawgit.com/)

Answer (score -1):

The file you're attempting to import is a just GitHub viewer for the file. To import the raw data for the file, you'd want to use this code below:

```html
<script>
   const source = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<username>/<repo>/master/index.js';
   fetch(source).then((response) => {
      return response.text()
   }).then((response) => {
      eval(response);
   }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(`An error occured while attempting to load the "${source}" resource!`);
      console.error(error);
   });
</script>
```

Since the GitHub website does not directly allow the import of their user content, you will need to wrap your source URL in the above fetch-eval block to fetch the file content directly.

Comment: This wouldn't work either: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19285701/12513827

Comment: @JohnnyLeek i updated the response, this should work now.

Comment: Yep, just tested it. It works. Although "module is not define" came up, because i tested it in a browser. but i defined it and made exports a setter that console logged, and sure enough ,i got some output.

Comment: This answer is very old, and yeah, probably not gonna work anymore. But I'm sure there is a better solution out there than what I came up with